# Store values in a List using a For loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to store values from a loop in a list. My code is:

```
int count = 100;
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
{
    my code to get the text:
    m.gettextfromelement("xpath");
}
```

Need code to store values in a list

Comment: The question is not clear....

Comment: errr.... `List.Add`? Did you try and research anything?

Comment: I want to hold the text (countries) from a table column in  a list and sort it later on based on alphabetical order. 
i am using for loop to get those values but got stuck how to store that values in a list or collection

Comment: Your code still doesn't make sense. Also, what do you mean by 'table column in a list'? Are you working with a `List<T>` or some kind of database?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
int count = 100;
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
{
    list.Add("StringValue");
}
```

Comment: That code would create a list with 100 items that all have the value "StringValue".

Comment: the "StringValue" is for the value that he wants to put in the list

Comment: You've quoted it, so it will insert that specific string into the list each time it loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it...

```
var stringList = new List<string>(); // The list to store your text
var count = 100;
for (var iteration = 0; iteration <= count; iteration++)
{
    //Code to get the text...
    //Code to get the specific element - var specificElement = m.gettextfromelement("xpath");
    //Finally, you "Add()" the specific element text to the list as...
    stringList.Add(specificElement);
}
```

All the Data Structures available in C# are available on MSDN website. List's page is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), FYI. [dotnetpearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) is another website for C# that I've often visited.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<string>();
int count = 100;
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
{
    list.Add(m.gettextfromelement("xpath"));
}
```